# how to get a density plot with fill where group has 10 categories

Tags: r, ggplot2

data looks like the following sample

|Species| |logSDM|  |UseCategories|
| X |    | 3.14 |   |AnimalFood|
|Y |     | 4.30 |   |Medicines|
|Z |     |9.3 |    | Materials|
|L |     |2.1 |    |HumanFood|
|X |     |1.1 |    |Medicine|
|F |     |3.5 |    |Fuels|

the `UseCategories` variable have 10 categories. I am getting a plot where I can not differentiate among different categories

```
ggplot(data=final, aes(x=logSDM, fill=UseCategories)) +
 geom_density(adjust=1) +
 theme_ipsum() +
 facet_wrap(~UseCategories) +
 theme([enter image description here][1]
   legend.position="none",
   panel.spacing = unit(0.1, "lines"),
   axis.ticks.x=element_blank()
 )
```

The plot I got:

[the plots are apparently the same. It is difficult to differentiate the data from the plots]

Comment: Fahmida, welcome to SO. You will find many friends here, if you provide a so-called reproducible/representative example. If you provide 10-20 lines of your data set `final`, we have an idea about how your data looks like. Check `dput()` or `head()` for this. The code fragment you provided is garbled, e.g. it includes partly the reference to the pic you wanted to append. ... OK. From a code perspective you assign the fill colour and your facets to  `UseCategoies`. Check whether the `facet_wrap( . ~ UseCategories)` helps to break out the different groups you want to have.

Comment: @Ray, I am new here and really confused about how to add my sample data.

Comment: no prob. If the above does not ring a bell, please read up on MRE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. The other option is you "translate" your problem to a built-in dataset like `iris` or `mtcars`. This allows to reproduce your problem/question, and work with you through your struggles. Adding a plot helps to show what your text is referring to. The built in "add your plot"/browse should get you there.